# Strange string behaviour with character '¡'

Tags: php, string, character

Please, have a look at this:

```
$str = '¡hola!'; // '¡' is the spanish opening exclamation mark

echo $str{0}; // prints nothing
echo $str{1}; // prints �
echo $str{2}; // prints h
```

The php script has UTF-8 encoding and I get the same results executing it as apache module or CLI.
PHP version: 5.4.6

Why I'm getting this strange results?

Comment: Looks like ¡ is a multi-byte character .. why do you want to access it via `[]`?

Comment: Multi-byte strings. `¡` is a two byte character [00A1] which is why you get nothing for the first byte, and garbage for the second.

Comment: @Peter It's not a browser encoding problem, indexing a string by [] or {} is not multi-byte safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that ¡ is actually a multibyte character in UTF, which PHP does not handle properly through array access (`[0]`). You'll want to look into the multibyte functions instead: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

This should work as you expect:

```
$str = '¡hola!';

echo mb_substr($str, 0, 1, 'UTF-8'); // prints ¡
echo mb_substr($str, 1, 1, 'UTF-8'); // prints h
echo mb_substr($str, 2, 1, 'UTF-8'); // prints o
```

Answer (score 4):

Indexing a string by `[]` or `{}` is not multi-byte safe.

Use multibyte-functions instead, like [mb_substr](http://php.net/mb_substr)